# Menu in a simple java game

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I created a GUI named Menu class for my Start, Help and Exit button. my problem is my game won't start, it hangs everytime I press the Start button. Can someone check my error and explain it to me because its my case study at school.

---

```
package spaceSip;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;

import java.awt.event.*;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;




public class Menu extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    private JLabel titleL;
    private JButton startB, helpB, exitB;

    static JFrame frame1 = new JFrame();

    public Menu()
    {
        frame1.setSize(500,250);

        Container mainP = frame1.getContentPane();
        mainP.setLayout(null);

        titleL = new JLabel("WELCOME");
        startB = new JButton("Start");
        helpB = new JButton("Help");
        exitB = new JButton("Exit");


        mainP.add(titleL);
        titleL.setFont(new Font("Chiller",Font.BOLD,50));
        titleL.setBounds(100, 30, 200, 50);

        mainP.add(startB);
        startB.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_S);
        startB.setBounds(200, 80, 100, 20);

        mainP.add(helpB);
        helpB.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_H);
        helpB.setBounds(200, 100, 100, 20);


        mainP.add(exitB);
        exitB.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_E);
        exitB.setBounds(200, 120, 100, 20);


        startB.addActionListener(this);
        helpB.addActionListener(this);
        exitB.addActionListener(this);

        frame1.setVisible(true);
        frame1.setResizable(false);


    }


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        String key = e.getActionCommand();

        if(key == "Start")
        {
            frame1.dispose();
            new SpaceShipMain();
        }

        else if(key == "Help")
        {

        }

        else
            System.exit(0);
    }

    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        new Menu();
    }

}
```

---

```
package spaceSip;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;

public class SpaceShipMain implements MouseListener
{

    private JFrame background;
    private SpaceShipPanel back;

    public static boolean paused;
    public static boolean crashed;
    public static boolean started;
    public static boolean playedOnce;        

    public boolean goingUp;
    private double upCount;

    public static int distance;
    public static int maxDistance;

    public final int XPOS;
    public final int NUMRECS;
    public final int RECHEIGHT;
    public final int RECWIDTH;

    private int moveIncrement;
    private int numSmoke;

    private ArrayList<SpaceShipImage> toprecs;
    private ArrayList<SpaceShipImage> bottomrecs;
    private ArrayList<SpaceShipImage> middlerecs;
    private ArrayList<SpaceShipImage> smoke;
    private SpaceShipImage helicopter;


    public SpaceShipMain()
    {
        NUMRECS = 100;
        RECHEIGHT = 70;
        RECWIDTH = 30;
        XPOS = 200;
        playedOnce = false;
        maxDistance = 0;

        load(new File("C:\\Users/Travelmate/workspace/GAME/src/spaceSip/Best.txt"));

        initiate();
    }

    public void load(File file)
    {
        try
        {
            Scanner reader = new Scanner(file);
            while(reader.hasNext())
            {
                int value = reader.nextInt();
                if(value > maxDistance)
                    maxDistance = value;
            }
        }
        catch(IOException i )
        {
            System.out.println("Error. "+i);
        }
    }

    public void save()
    {
        FileWriter out;
        try
        {
            out = new FileWriter("C:\\Users/Travelmate/workspace/GAME/src/spaceSip/Best.txt");
            out.write("" + maxDistance);
            out.close();
        }
        catch(IOException i)
        {
            System.out.println("Error: "+i.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void initiate()
    {
        if(!playedOnce)
        {
            background = new JFrame("Space Ship Game"); 
            background.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //closes the program when the window is closed
            background.setResizable(false); //don't allow the user to resize the window
            background.setSize(new Dimension(800,500));
            background.setVisible(true);

            back = new SpaceShipPanel("C:\\Users/Travelmate/workspace/GAME/src/spaceSip/starfield.jpg");
            background.add(back);

            back.addMouseListener(this);
        }
        playedOnce = true;
        goingUp = false;
        paused = false;
        crashed = false;
        started = false;

        distance = 0;
        upCount = 0;

        moveIncrement = 2;
        numSmoke = 15;


        toprecs = new ArrayList<SpaceShipImage>();
        middlerecs = new ArrayList<SpaceShipImage>();
        bottomrecs = new ArrayList<SpaceShipImage>();
        smoke = new ArrayList<SpaceShipImage>();

        helicopter = new SpaceShipImage("C:\\Users/Travelmate/workspace/GAME/src/spaceSip/rocketship.GIF",XPOS,200);

        for(int x = 0; x < NUMRECS; x++)
            toprecs.add(new SpaceShipImage("C:\\Users/Travelmate/workspace/GAME/src/spaceSip/rec2.JPG",RECWIDTH*x,5));
        for(int x = 0; x < NUMRECS; x++)
            bottomrecs.add(new SpaceShipImage("C:\\Users/Travelmate/workspace/GAME/src/spaceSip/rec2.JPG",RECWIDTH*x,410));

        middlerecs.add(new SpaceShipImage("C:\\Users/Travelmate/workspace/GAME/src/spaceSip/asteroid2.jpg",1392,randomMidHeight()));
        middlerecs.add(new SpaceShipImage("C:\\Users/Travelmate/workspace/GAME/src/spaceSip/asteroid2.jpg",1972,randomMidHeight()));


        drawRectangles();
    }

    public void drawRectangles()
    {
        long last = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long lastCopter = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long lastSmoke = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long lastSound = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int firstUpdates = 0;
        double lastDistance = (double)System.currentTimeMillis();
        while(true)
        {
            if(!paused && !crashed && started && (double)System.currentTimeMillis() - (double)(2900/40) > lastDistance)
            {   
                lastDistance = System.currentTimeMillis();
                distance++;
            }   


            if(!paused && !crashed && started && System.currentTimeMillis() - 10 > lastCopter)
            {
                lastCopter = System.currentTimeMillis();
                updateCopter();
                updateMiddle();
            }
            if(!paused && !crashed && started && System.currentTimeMillis() - 100 > last)
            {
                last = System.currentTimeMillis();
                updateRecs();
            }
            if(!paused && !crashed && started && System.currentTimeMillis() - 75 > lastSmoke)
            {
                lastSmoke = System.currentTimeMillis();
                if (firstUpdates < numSmoke)
                {
                    firstUpdates++;
                    smoke.add(new SpaceShipImage("C:\\Users/Travelmate/workspace/GAME/src/spaceSip/smoke.GIF",187,helicopter.getY()));
                    for(int x = 0; x < firstUpdates; x++)
                        smoke.set(x,new SpaceShipImage("C:\\Users/Travelmate/workspace/GAME/src/spaceSip/smoke.GIF",smoke.get(x).getX() - 12, smoke.get(x).getY()));
                }
                else
                {
                    for(int x = 0; x < numSmoke - 1; x++)
                        smoke.get(x).setY(smoke.get(x+1).getY());
                    smoke.set(numSmoke - 1,new SpaceShipImage("C:\\Users/Travelmate/workspace/GAME/src/spaceSip/smoke.GIF",187,helicopter.getY()));
                }
                    }
                    back.updateImages(middlerecs,helicopter,smoke);
                }
    }

    public void updateRecs()
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < (NUMRECS - 1); x++) //move all but the last rectangle 1 spot to the left
        {
            toprecs.set(x,new SpaceShipImage("C:\\Users/Travelmate/workspace/GAME/src/spaceSip/rec2.JPG",RECWIDTH*x,toprecs.get(x+1).getY()));
            bottomrecs.set(x,new SpaceShipImage("C:\\Users/Travelmate/workspace/GAME/src/spaceSip/rec2.JPG",RECWIDTH*x,bottomrecs.get(x+1).getY()));
        }

    }



    public void randomDrop()
    {
        toprecs.get(26).setY(toprecs.get(26).getY() + (463 - bottomrecs.get(26).getY()));
        bottomrecs.get(26).setY(463);
    }




    public int randomMidHeight()
    {
        int max = 10000;
        int min = 0;

        for(int x = 0; x < NUMRECS; x++)
        {
            if(toprecs.get(x).getY() > min)
                min = (int)toprecs.get(x).getY();
            if(bottomrecs.get(x).getY() < max)
                max = (int)bottomrecs.get(x).getY();
        }
        min += RECHEIGHT;
        max -= (RECHEIGHT + min);
        return min + (int)(Math.random() * max);
    }

    //moves the randomly generated middle rectangles
    public void updateMiddle()
    {
        if(middlerecs.get(0).getX() > -1 * RECWIDTH)
        {
            middlerecs.set(0,new SpaceShipImage("C:\\Users/Travelmate/workspace/GAME/src/spaceSip/asteroid.gif",middlerecs.get(0).getX() - (RECWIDTH/5), middlerecs.get(0).getY()));
            middlerecs.set(1,new SpaceShipImage("C:\\Users/Travelmate/workspace/GAME/src/spaceSip/asteroid.gif",middlerecs.get(1).getX() - (RECWIDTH/5), middlerecs.get(1).getY()));
        }
        else
        {
            middlerecs.set(0,new SpaceShipImage("C:\\Users/Travelmate/workspace/GAME/src/spaceSip/asteroid.gif",middlerecs.get(1).getX() - (RECWIDTH/5), middlerecs.get(1).getY()));
            middlerecs.set(1,new SpaceShipImage("C:\\Users/Travelmate/workspace/GAME/src/spaceSip/asteroid.gif",middlerecs.get(0).getX() + 580,randomMidHeight()));
        }
    }

    public boolean shoot()
    {
        for(int x = 3; x <= 7; x++)
            if(helicopter.getY() >= bottomrecs.get(x).getY())
                return true;

        for(int y = 3; y <= 7; y++)
                if(helicopter.getY() <= toprecs.get(y).getY())
                    return true;
        for(int z = 0; z <= 1; z++)
            if(isInMidRange(z))
                return true;
        return false;
    }

    public boolean isInMidRange(int num)
    {
        Rectangle middlecheck = new Rectangle((int)middlerecs.get(num).getX(),(int)middlerecs.get(num).getY(),RECWIDTH,RECHEIGHT);
        Rectangle coptercheck = new Rectangle((int)helicopter.getX(),(int)helicopter.getY(),70,48); //asteroid X and y bump
        return middlecheck.intersects(coptercheck);
    }

    public void crash()
    {
        crashed = true;
        if(distance > maxDistance) 
        {
            maxDistance = distance;
            save();
        }
        int reply = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "               RESTART ?", "GAME OVER", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);    
        if(reply == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
            initiate();

        else 
            System.exit(0);


        initiate();
    }

    //moves the spaceship
    public void updateCopter()
    {
        upCount += .10;
        if(goingUp)
        {
            if(upCount < 3.5)
                helicopter.setPosition(XPOS,(double)(helicopter.getY() - (.3 + upCount)));
            else
                helicopter.setPosition(XPOS,(double)(helicopter.getY() - (1.2 + upCount)));
            helicopter.setImage("C:\\Users/Travelmate/workspace/GAME/src/spaceSip/rocketship.GIF"); 
        }
        else
        {
            if(upCount < 1)
                helicopter.setPosition(XPOS,(double)(helicopter.getY() + upCount));
            else
                helicopter.setPosition(XPOS,(double)(helicopter.getY() + (1.2 + upCount)));
            helicopter.setImage("C:\\Users/Travelmate/workspace/GAME/src/spaceSip/rocketship.GIF");
        }
        if(shoot())
            crash();
    }

    //Called when the mouse exits the game window
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)
    {
            paused = true;
    }

    //Called when the mouse enters the game window
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
    {

    }

    //Called when the mouse is released
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
    {
        goingUp = false;
        upCount = -1;
        if(paused)
            paused = false;
    }

    //Called when the mouse is pressed
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
    {
        if (!started)
            started = true;
        goingUp = true;
        upCount = 0;
    }

    //Called when the mouse is released
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
    {

    }
}
```

---

```
package spaceSip;

import java.awt.Image;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class SpaceShipImage
{
    private Image image;        //The picture
    private double x;           //X position
    private double y;           //Y position

    //Construct a new Moving Image with image, x position, and y position given
    public SpaceShipImage(Image img, double xPos, double yPos)
    {
        image = img;
        x = xPos;
        y = yPos;
    }

    //Construct a new Moving Image with image (from file path), x position, and y position given
    public SpaceShipImage(String path, double xPos, double yPos)
    {
        this(new ImageIcon(path).getImage(), xPos, yPos);   
            //easiest way to make an image from a file path in Swing
    }

    //They are set methods.  I don't feel like commenting them.
    public void setPosition(double xPos, double yPos)
    {
        x = xPos;
        y = yPos;
    }

    public void setImage(String path)
    {
        image = new ImageIcon(path).getImage();
    }

    public void setY(double newY)
    {
        y = newY;
    }

    public void setX(double newX)
    {
        x = newX;
    }

    //Get methods which I'm also not commenting
    public double getX()
    {
        return x;
    }

    public double getY()
    {
        return y;
    }

    public Image getImage()
    {
        return image;
    }
}
```

---

```
package spaceSip;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

class SpaceShipPanel extends JPanel 
{
    private Image background;           
    private ArrayList<SpaceShipImage> middle;
    private SpaceShipImage copter;
    private ArrayList<SpaceShipImage> smoke;

    //Constructs a new ImagePanel with the background image specified by the file path given
    public SpaceShipPanel(String img) 
    {
        this(new ImageIcon(img).getImage());    
            //The easiest way to make images from file paths in Swing
    }

    //Constructs a new ImagePanel with the background image given
    public SpaceShipPanel(Image img)
    {
        background = img;
        Dimension size = new Dimension(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null));    
            //Get the size of the image
        //Thoroughly make the size of the panel equal to the size of the image
        //(Various layout managers will try to mess with the size of things to fit everything)
        setPreferredSize(size);
        setMinimumSize(size);
        setMaximumSize(size);
        setSize(size);


        middle = new ArrayList<SpaceShipImage>();
        smoke = new ArrayList<SpaceShipImage>();
    }

    //This is called whenever the computer decides to repaint the window
    //It's a method in JPanel that I've overwritten to paint the background and foreground images
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
    {
        //Paint the background with its upper left corner at the upper left corner of the panel
        g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, null); 
        //Paint each image in the foreground where it should go

        for(SpaceShipImage img : middle)
            g.drawImage(img.getImage(), (int)(img.getX()), (int)(img.getY()), null);
        for(SpaceShipImage img : smoke)
            g.drawImage(img.getImage(), (int)(img.getX()), (int)(img.getY()), null);
        if(copter != null)
            g.drawImage(copter.getImage(), (int)(copter.getX()), (int)(copter.getY()), null);
        drawStrings(g);
    }

    public void drawStrings(Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.BOLD,20));
        g.drawString("Distance: " + SpaceShipMain.distance,30,440);
        g.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.BOLD,20));
        if (SpaceShipMain.distance > SpaceShipMain.maxDistance)
            g.drawString("Best: " + SpaceShipMain.distance,650,440);
        else
            g.drawString("Best: " + SpaceShipMain.maxDistance,650,440);
        if(SpaceShipMain.paused)
        {

                g.setFont(new Font("Chiller",Font.BOLD,72));
                g.drawString("Paused",325,290);
                g.setFont(new Font("Chiller",Font.BOLD,30));
                g.drawString("Click to unpause.",320,340);
        }
    }

    //Replaces the list of foreground images with the one given, and repaints the panel
    public void updateImages(ArrayList<SpaceShipImage> newMiddle,SpaceShipImage newCopter,ArrayList<SpaceShipImage> newSmoke)
    {
        copter = newCopter;
        middle = newMiddle;
        smoke = newSmoke;
        repaint();  //This repaints stuff... you don't need to know how it works
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post relevant parts only. Your question is vague.

Comment: And Nulllayout is Evil : http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/GUI/layouts/nulllayout.html  .... Use LayoutManager :) ... and why you extends from a JFrame... use it as field or something else but not extend it when you gave him no special things.

Comment: hmmn, i guess i dont have any problem at that sir. Do you think my program has a bug ? i can run my SpaceShipMain() in a main method but not in the Button

Comment: I extends it from JFrame because I need that GUI for creating my Menu game sir.

Answer (score 2):

You compare Strings with `equals`(value equality) not with `==`(reference equality). For more information read this previous question [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)
As @AndrewThompson always advice don't use `NullLayout`

> Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different
>   screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not
>   conducive to exact placement of components.  To organize the
>   components for a robust GUI, instead use layout managers, or
>   [combinations of
>   them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556)<sup>1</sup>, along
>   with layout padding & borders for [white
>   space](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17874717/418556)<sup>2</sup>.

As you say that your gui is blocked, that may be cause some of your execution code takes too more time and it's executed in the same thread as gui stuff ([The Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)). As you have a `while(true)` that's block the gui so use a [SwingTimer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for execute repeatidly task or if that code that takes long time execute it in a background thread using a [Swing Worker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html). Here you have a complete [example](http://www.javacreed.com/swing-worker-example/). When you perform custom painting you should override `paintComponent` and in first line you have to call `super.paintComponent(..)` to follow correct chaining. Read more in [Painting in AWT-Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html).
Another error i see is that you are adding components after calling `setVisible(true)` without calling `revalidate()` `repaint()`. So i recommend to first add components to container then call `setVisible(true)` at final step.

Comment: i have no problem at == sign sir. my problem is. when i call the constructor SpaceShipMain() from the Start button, the game hangs

Comment: @jankryss i edited but you should still compare string with `equals` . The problem may rely in that you are blocking the EDT, you have to use another thread to call `load`.

Comment: i already did what you said @nachokk but still hangs. i added all the class in my question, can run it for me and check my error ?

Comment: @jankryss i found another error... you have to call `super.paintComponent()` when you make custom painting.

Comment: ok got it sir, so what is the main error in my program causing the game to hang ? you will notice it when you press the Start button

Comment: @jankryss i edited you have a lot of errors. but when you put `while(true)` that's block your gui. Use a swing timer for that!. I edited answer.